# A discrete-time system is positively stabilizable iff (A,B) is stabilizable and the eigenvalues are in the open unit disk

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, discrete-time

I'm currently busy with some research in positive controllability and positive stabilizability for discrete time systems.
In an article of M.E. Evans and D.N.P. Murthy ("Controllability of discrete-time systems with positive controls"), it is shown that the system:

$$x(k+1) = Ax(k) + bu(k), x(k) \in \mathbb{R}^n, u(k) \in \mathbb{R}_+$$

is completely controllable (so positive controllable, since $u$ is restricted to the positive numbers) iff

1. rank[$b$ $Ab$ ... $A^{(n-1)}b$] = n
2. A has no eigenvalues $\lambda \geq 0$

But now I'm reading an article of P. de Leenheer and D. Nesic ("A note on stabilizing and time-optimal controllers for discrete-time linear systems with positive controls"), in which they state that the same system is positively stabilizable iff

1. (A,b) is stabilizable
2. $\sigma(A) \cap [1, \infty) = \emptyset$.

I want to look at why the statements about the eigenvalues are different, however I find the proof of Leenheer quite short and don't understand it.
So I thought, maybe somebody can help me? I don't need a full proof or something (if you want you can share), just a step in the right direction.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, they are quite similar. When you are looking for stabilizability you don't care for the eigenvalues that are already stable. You can always left them "untouched" so you don't need them to be controllable for stabilization purposes. So, you only want controllability for the unstable eigenvalues, which is compatible with the first theorem.

Comment: I don't quite yet understand, stable eigenvalues lie within the open unit disk, right? So for positive stabilizability you say we don't need to look at those, but what about the negative eigenvalues? And for controllability you say we also only look at the not stable eigenvalues, but I would say that those are $\lambda \geq 1$ and $\lambda \leq -1$

Comment: Do you mean that whenever an eigenvalue is smaller than 0, it can be controlled to stability, and that whenever an eigenvalue lies within the open unit disk it is stable. Therefore only the eigenvalues greater than 1 are a problem for the stabilization?

Comment: @Sabine That is exactly what I meant.